# Aura component on load gives an error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

There is a record edit form in my component which has 4 fields. On load I am getting a weird error. The issue occurs due to the field IncumbentDevice__c which is a picklist field at the object level. Below is my component markup and the screenshot of the error I am receiving:

```
<aura:component controller="ImpServicesRequestFormController" implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="formData" type="ImpServicesRequestFormController.ImpRequestFormWrapper"/>

<div class="mainDiv" style="padding:10px">
    
    <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Implementation_Services_Request__c">
        
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="formInput" class="input slds-var-p-top_small" fieldName="NumberOfFacilities__c" value="{!v.formData.impServiceRequest.NumberOfFacilities__c}" required="true" ></lightning:inputField>
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="formInput" class="input slds-var-p-top_small" fieldName="IncumbentDevice__c" value="{!v.formData.impServiceRequest.IncumbentDevice__c}" required="true" ></lightning:inputField>
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="formInput" class="input slds-var-p-bottom_large" fieldName="NumberOfClinicalEducationSeats__c" value="{!v.formData.impServiceRequest.NumberOfClinicalEducationSeats__c}" required="true" ></lightning:inputField>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller.js

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getImpRequestFormHelper(component);
},
})
```

Helper.js

```
({
getImpRequestFormHelper : function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.getImpRequestForm");
    action.setParams({
        "recordId" : component.get('v.recordId') 
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS"){
            console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.formData", response.getReturnValue());
            
        }
        else{
            console.log('in error')
            
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please check if user has access to field IncumbentDevice__c  and also make sure the object doesn't have any record type. if it has then you will need to provide the record type id to `<lightning:recordEditForm>`

Comment: Yes the user has permission to the field and there aren't any record types.
The lightning component is loaded on click of Edit button of Implementation_Services_Request__c record page. If I refresh the component I don't face the issue.

Comment: What are you doing in your 'doInit' controller method?
Can you please paste complete code.

Comment: I am fetching the record data which triggered the component. I checked by removing the doinit. Still the issue persists. I have added the controller and the helper code.

Comment: How are you setting the value to the formData attribute? I suspect that this is null/undefined

Comment: Thanks @rahulgawale. I added an aura:if that ensures the fields are loaded only if fromData is not null and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Krish You don't need to use a server-side call for that, you could have just set recordId on the lightning:recordEditForm, and it would load the data for you automatically.